# Django passing foreign key to view

Tags: python, django, forms, model

Hi Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction, i am learning Django through Tango with Django and i am also following along with the official Django tutorials as well as creating my own Django app for purchase orders.

I need to understand how I can access the Foreign key details of another Model and save it using forms. Basically my app has Orders and Suppliers when creating an order I can get the supplier foreign key options to appear on the form but when I save it I also want to save with the `suppier_name` into the orders table currently it just saves with the `supplier_id`, I have searched through many examples of different scenarios but just can't understand it thanks.

view.py

```
def add_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return orders(request)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = OrderForm()

    context_dict = {'form':form}

    return render(
        request,
        'purchaseorders/add_order.html',
        context_dict
    )
```

model.py

```
# Create your models here.

class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    supplier_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True
    )
    supplier_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    supplier_website = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.supplier_name)
        super(Supplier,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.supplier_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplier_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Suppliers"


class Order(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    po_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ordered_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField()
    supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    net_value = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=10
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.po_number
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from PurchaseOrders.models import Supplier, Order

class SupplierForm(forms.ModelForm):
    supplier_code = forms.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        help_text="Please enter a unique code"
    )
    supplier_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Please enter the Suppliers full name"
    )
    supplier_email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Please enter a email address"
    )
    supplier_website = forms.URLField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Please enter a website"
    )
    slug = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        required=False
    )

# an inline class to provide additional information on the form
    class Meta:
        # provide an association between the ModelForm and model
        model = Supplier
        fields = (
            'supplier_code', 'supplier_name', 
            'supplier_email', 'supplier_website'
        )

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #list all form details except the Foreignkey connection
    po_number = forms.IntegerField(
        help_text="please enter a PO Number"
    )
    ordered_by = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        help_text="please enter your name"
    )
    order_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        help_text="please enter a date of order"
    )
    #supplier_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Supplier.objects.all()
    )
    net_value = forms.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=10,
        help_text="please enter a net amount"
    )

    class Meta:
        # provide an association between the ModelForm and model
        model = Order
```

html

```
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- New line -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Purchase Orders</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <img src="{% static "purchaseorders/images/po_icon.png" %}" 
    alt="PO icon" />
    <h1>Add a Order</h1>

    <form id="order_form" method="post" 
    action="/PurchaseOrders/add_order/{{ supplier }}">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        <ul style="list-style-type:none ">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <li></li>
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            <li>{{ field }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Order" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's unnecessary duplication of data. An order always has access to the supplier name through the foreign key, so there is no point saving a separate copy of that name.

Comment: Ye valid point i suppose i am just trying to understand how i could do it if i wanted to and then like you point out realise there is no need.

Comment: my other thinking was that if i instead used another field from the Supplier Model how could i also find the id based on that field and then save it , when i tried doing that i would get integrity null constraint errors on foreignkey,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with the question as-asked, you could capture this data in the model's save() method:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    [...]
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.supplier_id is not None:
            self.supplier_name = self.supplier.supplier_name
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

HOWEVER, although there are some cases where the above might be correct (such as if supplier name is expected to change), it is much more typical to simply access a related field through the existing relationship, ex:

```
myorder.supplier.supplier_name
```

Comment: Thanks i got the myorder.supplier.supplier_name display now in my template and i understand my its the better answer.